# Запись логов в БД

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, логирование

Всем добрый день. Хочу настроить логирование сервиса в БД Postgres с помощью ILogger. Сервис логгинга добавил. Сейчас запись идет в консоль. Как настроить запись логов БД?

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {services.AddLogging();}
```

Comment: Взгляните [сюда 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42715473/6468198) и [сюда 2](https://damienbod.com/2017/03/29/net-core-asp-net-core-logging-with-nlog-and-postgresql/). Здесь на примере `NLog` осуществляется логирование в Postgres.

Comment: Спасибо. Пробую реализовывать.

Comment: По второй ссылке рабочий способ, за исключением некоторых моментов по настройке класса Startup и Program для тех кто использует Net.Core 2.2.

Comment: Можете оформить это как ответ: остальным будет тоже полезно это знать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По ссылке [Logging with NLog and PostgreSQL](https://damienbod.com/2017/03/29/net-core-asp-net-core-logging-with-nlog-and-postgresql/)

можно найти основную инструкцию по настройке NLOG с записью логов в БД Postgress и txt. С некоторыми исключениям для тех кто работает с Net.Core 2.2 (У меня, например, VS-2017). 
В классе Startup прописываем:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

и

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("configDir", $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\");

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }


    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

Для тех у кого Net.Core 3.0 можно брать весь код по ссылке.